# How does this mob grapple?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, gm-techniques, published-adventures

The party is teleported into the middle of a dretch mob in the adventure *Fortress of the Yuan-ti* (48).

- How many creatures can this dretch mob grapple?
- Does this dretch mob's grapple check suffer a −20 penalty for each creature it grapples after the first?

Comment: How many dretches are in the mob?

Comment: @GMJoe "A mob is a Gargantuan creature composed of... forty-eight... Medium creatures" (*DMG2* 59). Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what options the mob has. Per DMGII p.60. mobs have attack options including one or both of *Expert Grappler* (they can grapple multiple people, with no -20 penalty beyond the first) and *Trample*.

Looking at that mob's stat block in Fortress, I see both *Expert Grappler* and *Trample* listed under Attack Options.  Therefore they can grapple however many characters can fit in their area and do not suffer a -20 penalty.